# How to do formatted printing with jq?

Tags: bash, command-line, text-formatting, printf, jq

`jq` has built-in ability to convert numbers to string or concatenate strings.
How can I format strings inside jq similar to `printf` like padding (%4s).

For example, how can I force number to occupy 10 char spaces with left alignment?
`echo '{"title" : "A sample name", "number" : 1214}' | jq '(.title) + " " + (.number | tostring)'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to not trying to do it in `jq`, and instead use `jq` to output a shell statement to do it in the shell instead:

```bsh
eval "$(
    jq -r -n '
        { "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 } |
        [ "printf", "%s %10s\\n", .title, .number ] | @sh'
)"
```

or,

```bsh
eval "$(
    printf '%s\n' '{ "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 }' |
    jq -r '[ "printf", "%s %10d\\n", .title, .number ] | @sh'
)"
```

or,

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '{ "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 }' |
{
    eval "$(
        jq -r '[ "printf", "%s %10s\\n", .title, .number ] | @sh'
    )"
}
```

The `jq` command would output

```bsh
'printf' '%s %10d\n' 'A sample name' 1214
```

using the `@sh` operator to properly quote each bit of the command safely.
When evaluated, this would output

```
A sample name       1214
```

---

A similar approach, but giving you two variable assignments instead:

```bsh
jq -r -n '
    { "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 } |
    @sh "title=\(.title)",
    @sh "number=\(.number)"'
```

You would then use these variables in your script:

```bsh
unset -v title number

eval "$(
    jq -r -n '
        { "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 } |
        @sh "title=\(.title)",
        @sh "number=\(.number)"'
)"

printf '%s %10s\n' "$title" "$number"
```

---

For cases where the data is known to be *nice* (the title can't contain newlines, for example), you could possibly do

```bsh
jq -r -n '
    { "title": "A sample name", "number": 1214 } |
    [ .title, .number ] | @sh' |
xargs printf '%s %10s\n'
```

That is, make sure that the data is quoted, and then pass it to `printf` in the shell (this would call the *external* utility `printf`, not a shell built-in).

Comment: Beware `jq` outputs numbers in English format (with `.` as the decimal radix character for instance), while `printf` (for those implementations that accept floats for `%d`) expects it in  the locale format. Several `printf` implementations like that of zsh or ksh88/ksh93 (those found as `sh` on some systems) will interpret arguments for `%d` as arithmetic expressions and as such can execute arbitrary commands, so it would be important to sanitise the input if those `.number` can't be guaranteed to be numbers. Using `%10s` instead of `%10d` would avoid the problem.

Answer (score 21):

`jq` can reference expressions inside string using `\(foo)`

> [String interpolation - `\(foo)`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation)
>
> Inside a string, you can put an expression inside parens after a backslash. Whatever the expression returns will be interpolated into the string.

```
jq '"The input was \(.), which is one less than \(.+1)"' <<<  42
```

Result:

```
"The input was 42, which is one less than 43"
```

Comment: This is great. Any jq syntax is valid between the parentheses. For example, array iteration, field access. So `echo '["a", "b", "c"]' | jq -r '"Testing \(.[])"'` yields 3 lines of output  `Testing a`, `Testing b`, and `Testing c`

Comment: @JimmieTyrrell that's cool, thanks. I can't even process that mentally.

Answer (score 16):

`jq` does not have `printf`. One way could be; [Partially taken from here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/614):

```
echo '{"title" : "A sample name", "number" : 1214}' | 
jq '(.title) + " " + 
    (.number | tostring | (" " * (10 - length)) + .)'
```

Perhaps better added as a module.

---

Personally I quickly find `jq` lines to be somewhat messy and resort to perl, python, php or similar *if doing anything beyond the basics*. (But that is me :P)

E.g with php:

```php
#! /usr/bin/env php
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://stdin"));

printf("%s: %10d\n", $data->title, $data->number);

?>
```

(Would add error-checking etc as well of course.)